# Fragments in Navigation drawer creates new object everytime when switched between them

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a navigation drawer with multiple fragments by referring this link :-

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/28/navigation-drawer-android/

In another application, i created fragment tab host and save their states by showing and hiding them in tab listener if their objects are not null by calling `setRetainiInstance(true)` in the respective fragments.

Is is possible to save the states of the fragments in the navigation drawer such that once they have been called and we navigate to that fragment again, it should appear as it is?

Below is the question for tab host fragments

[FragmentTabs creating new Fragment objects every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945347/fragmenttabs-creating-new-fragment-objects-every-time)